# Controlar Porta Serial usando Aplicação Web

Tags: php

Preciso comunicar meu sistema com a porta serial do computador **Cliente**, o detalhe é que com PHP posso usar o `fopen`, mas não quero acessar a porta serial do servidor, mas sim do cliente.

Pensei em usar um plugin, seja em Java ou em Flash, alguém faz ideia de como eu posso fazer essa comunicação.

OBS: A comunicação será com uma impressora fiscal que trabalha na porta serial.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta...

Comment: Pergunta interessante, porém trabalhe ela melhor, explicando essa parte do `fopen`. Veja [ask].

Comment: Relevante (eu acho): http://www.phpavancado.net/node/398

Comment: Não sei se é possível, já que PHP trabalha do lado do servidor... Talvez com outra linguagem como javascript, que trabalha com o cliente, você consiga acessar os periféricos do computador do cliente...

Comment: Pergunta interessante. Mas acredito que você não usará o fopen. Você poderia enviar o que será impresso como Response, a qual será lida pelo Plugin Client Side e este enviará para a impressora ?

Comment: https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja tive que fazer esse tipo de trabalho em diversas aplicaçoes.

As soluçoes encontradas foram usar usar Applets Java ou instalar um pequeno serviço na maquina cliente que abre um porta e responde a requisicoes HTTP, assim podiamos fazer requisicoes Ajax usando JavaScript a esta porta no localhost. Esse serviço pode ser feito em uma linguagem que se comunique diretamente com a porta serial da maquina cliente.

Ja vi algumas aplicaçoes que usam ActiveX, porem eram restritas ao Internet Explorer.

Comment: Adendo: A solução por hora mais portável é Applets, por acessar recursos nativos da máquina cliente, precisará que o Applet esteja assinado.

Comment: Gostei da ideia, utilizarei Applets em java, como eu entendo bastante de Java para desktop fica mais fácil para mim.

Answer (score 4):

Além da excelente solução citada pelo colega, utilizando Java Applet, só para constar:
O Google Chrome oferece API para comunicar com a Porta Serial.

```
var writeSerial=function(str) {
  chrome.serial.send(connectionId, convertStringToArrayBuffer(str), onSend);
}
// Convert string to ArrayBuffer
var convertStringToArrayBuffer=function(str) {
  var buf=new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  var bufView=new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    bufView[i]=str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15926487/194717